# How to increment a variable like so in PHP

Tags: php

I have this script...

```
//initial value

$fund = 10;
$rebate = 0.01; // constant 1 percent
$maturity = 30; //days

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>Day1 fund: $' . $fund . '</li>';

//day1 value
$fund = incfund($fund); //should return $10.10
echo '<li>Day2 fund: $' . $fund . '</li>';

//day2 value
$fund = incfund($fund); //should return $10.20
echo '<li>Day3 fund: $' . $fund . '</li>';

//day3 value
$fund = incfund($fund); //should return $10.30
echo '<li>Day4 fund: $' . $fund . '</li>';

echo '</ul>';
//continue increasing the fund value daily until day 30...


//function to increase $fund

function incfund($x){
for($i = 0; $i<=$maturity; $i++){
$newfund = $x + $rebate;
$fund = $newfund;
return $fund;
}
}
```

currently if I run the script, it will output:

```
Day1 fund: $10
Day2 fund: $10
Day3 fund: $10
Day4 fund: $10
```

when I really want to output is:

```
Day1 fund: $10.10
Day2 fund: $10.20
Day3 fund: $10.30
Day4 fund: $10.40
...
...
Day30 fund: $13.00
```

basically, what I want to do is compute the 1% rebate and compound it to the original fund and then continue compounding until the maturity date.

what could be the problem why I cannot do what I want?

Comment: Try to change the first line to `$fund = 10.0;`?

Comment: You always return in the first iteration of your `for` loop. That makes the loop pretty pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your code

```
function incfund($x){
    for($i = 0; $i<=$maturity; $i++){
        $newfund = $x + $rebate;
        $fund = $newfund;
        return $fund;
    }
}
```

What it really do

```
function incfund($x){
    return $x+$rebate;
}
```

What you should change

```
function incfund($x){
    global $rebate;
    return $x+$rebate;
}
```

or

```
function incfund($x, $rebate){
    return $x+$rebate;
}
```

And change view layer for

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maturity; $i++, $fund = incfund($fund)) {
    echo '<li>Day'.$i.' fund: $' . $fund . '</li>';
}
```

But as you described your functionality all your code should look like

```
//initial value

$fund = 10;
$rebate_weekdays = 0.01; // constant 1 percent
$rebate_weekend = 0.02; // constant 1 percent
$maturity = 30; //days

echo '<ul>';

// show fund and continue increasing the fund value daily until day 30...
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maturity; $i++) {
    $rebate = (is_it_weekend($i)) ? $rebate_weekend: $rebate_weekdays;
    $curfund = incfund($fund, $i, $rebate);
    echo '<li>Day'.$i.' fund: $' . $curfund . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';

//function to calculate current $fund    
function incfund($fund, $x, $rebate){
    return $fund * (1 + $x * $rebate);
}
```

How to check that day you can find. It simply using http://php.net/mktime and http://php.net/date

Comment: you forgot the `;` in the `$curfund` statement :) but its the best answer so far! thank you

Comment: yep, sorry. fixed :) enjoy stackoverflow!

Comment: currently `$rebate` is constant. what if you want 2% on weekdays and 1% on weekend? is it possible to do that? thanks again

Comment: `Call to undefined function is_it_weekend() `

Answer (score 3):

pass `$rebate`,`$maturity` variables as function parameters.

```
function incfund($x,$rebate,$maturity){
...
}
```

Call function:

```
incfund($fund,$rebate,$maturity);
```

Comment: @GDB this was the best answer before until Electronick detailed suggestion came:) but it works using my original code! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, if you want formatting like 2 digits after decimal, you should use `number_format($number,2)`

It is in addition to GBD's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you really gonna do it like this here is how u can change method to do what you want

```
function incfund($x){
 global $maturity;
 global $fund;
 global $rebate;
  for($i = 0; $i<=$maturity; $i++){
     $newfund = $x+($x*$rebate);
     $newfund=number_format((float)$newfund, 2, '.', '');
     $fund = $newfund;
    return $fund;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and outputs what you want. I found easier to create the day inside the loop.

```
<?php

//function to increase $fund

function incfund(){
        $fund = 10;
        $rebate = 1; // constant 1 percent
        $maturity = 30; //days
        $html = '';
        $interest = ($fund / 100) * $rebate;
        for($i = 0; $i<=$maturity; $i++){
            $realInterest = $interest * $i;
            $html .= '<li>Day'.$i.' fund: $' . number_format($fund+$realInterest ,2) . '</li>';
        }
    echo $html;
}

echo incfund();
?>


Day0 fund: $10.00
Day1 fund: $10.10
Day2 fund: $10.20
Day3 fund: $10.30
Day4 fund: $10.40
Day5 fund: $10.50
Day6 fund: $10.60
Day7 fund: $10.70
Day8 fund: $10.80
Day9 fund: $10.90
Day10 fund: $11.00
Day11 fund: $11.10
Day12 fund: $11.20
Day13 fund: $11.30
Day14 fund: $11.40
Day15 fund: $11.50
Day16 fund: $11.60
Day17 fund: $11.70
Day18 fund: $11.80
Day19 fund: $11.90
Day20 fund: $12.00
Day21 fund: $12.10
Day22 fund: $12.20
Day23 fund: $12.30
Day24 fund: $12.40
Day25 fund: $12.50
Day26 fund: $12.60
Day27 fund: $12.70
Day28 fund: $12.80
Day29 fund: $12.90
Day30 fund: $13.00
```

Answer (score -2):

OK, since you calculate the result from the basic fund, you have to keep this value.

This should do it:

```
// initial
$fund = 10;
$rebate = 0.01; // constant 1 percent
$maturity = 30; //days

incfunds($fund, $rebate, $maturity);

function incfunds($fund, $rebate, $maturity) {
    echo "<ul>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $maturity; $i++) {
        echo "<li>Day{$i+1} fund:".($fund + (($fund/100) * $i*$rebate))."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

That's all.